# What is the quickest way to detect the maximum variable value in SAS

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to find an efficient way of detecting the maximum value of a date variable. One caveat of the data that I will receive daily, is that the date is recorded as text.

I would usually do it in the following way:

```
proc sql noprint ;
 select MAX(MDY(input(SUBSTRN(MyDate, 6, 2),2.), input(SUBSTRN(MyDate, 9, 2),2.), input(SUBSTRN(MyDate, 1, 4),4.))) as max_date FORMAT=date9.
 into :max_date
 from FooData;
quit;
```

In this case, the data contains more than 100m rows and running this code every days seems cumbersome. Can anyone think of a more efficient way to approach this issue?

Comment: Your dates seem to be stored in the yyyymmdd10 format, can you confirm that only the date is stored in the MyDate column? (i.e. no other text afterwards)

Comment: @Keith. I can confirm that there is no other text in this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice thing about YYYYMMDD is that when you sort it as a string, it also ends up sorted as a date (unlike, for example MM/DD/YY).  So just take the `max()`.

Comment: after not having to convert the character variables to Numeric, just looking for the MAX() value is lightning fast. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly simplify the `select` statement by using a single informat to read in the date, instead of 3 substring calculations.  It obviously needs to do this for every record, so it will still slow it down, but hopefully not as much as currently.

```
proc sql noprint ;
 select MAX(input(mydate,yymmdd10.)) as max_date FORMAT=date9.
 into :max_date
 from FooData;
quit;
```